# Can i update existing published website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, publishing

I have a basic question basically I have created an app which i hosted on private server.
Step I followed.

- Create Web
- Published it in a folder.
- Made application pool
- Add website on iis
- Gave physical path of that published folder
- Assigned ip address and port no.

Okay! so this is perfectly fine and it is running absolutely fine.

**scenario**

- Let say i have to update some functionality of app so is it possible
  to target existing published folder while publishing from visual
  studio after doing changes.
- Or should i delete the existing published folder and repeat that
  above process again?

Comment: If your changes are only in views(cshtml pages) or scripts then you can simply replace the view or script in published folder. If changes are in model or controller then you have to publish your code again.

Comment: I am asking that if i am publishing again than can i target the same published folder , and it will update the existing files?

Comment: Yes....defiantly.